# Implementing the shell "*" into a C program

Tags: c, linux, shell

My teacher asked me to do a program using execlp that will do the same as :
    `scp * mylogin@mycomputer:/home/mylogin/myfolder`

I've tried :

    `execlp("scp", "scp", "*", "mylogin@mycomputer:/home/mylogin/myfolder", 0)`

I found out that it doesn't work since it's the shell that convert * to files name.

Is there a way that I could do it, I don't really know how I could get all the files names into the execlp call?

I'm sorry if i'm not clear, it's just hard for me to explain :( but I'm really looking for any tips on how the "*" works it would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) to perform the glob match. Then allocate an array where you put the matching filenames and the other arguments to scp. You will not want to use `execlp()` but `execvp()` in this case as you now have an array instead of an argument list.

However, the assignment by itself is rather stupid: If you want shell wildcard expansion, use `system()` which executes the given command in a shell (with all its advantages and disadvantages).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the C standard library does not provide a function to scan a directory.  In *dirent.h,* which may be available on your platform, there are the *opendir()* function and its associates.  You can research that.

Other answers have mentioned *glob()* from *glob.h,* but that is also platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob(3)` function for expanding wildcards.